# How can i loop in treeView1 SelectedNode to the last childe node and go back to the level 0?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, nodes

I have this method:

```
public void RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(TreeNode ParentNode)
        {
            if (ParentNode.GetNodeCount(true) > 0)
            {
                int i = oParentNode.GetNodeCount(true);
                foreach (TreeNode subnode in ParentNode.Nodes)
                {
                    string ss = (string)subnode.Tag;
                    if (ss == "file")
                    {
                        DeleteFile(treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath + "\\" + subnode.Text, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

ParentNode is treeView1.SelectedNode

What i want to do is to loop first to the last child node for example if the selected node text is B
And if inside B there are child nodes that are directories so to get to the last one:

B/C/D/E

To get first to E search for files if there are files in E to delete them.
Then go back once level to D delete the files there too if there are any.
Then to C and then to delete files in B if there are any.

Then to delete the directories one by one: first to delete the last one: B/C/D/E then to delete the one before B/C/D then B/C and last to delete B

I know to identify if the variable ss is file or directory.
The method DeleteFile will delete each time a single file.
I also have a method RemoveDirectory in case ss is a directory.

The question is how can i do this recursive loop ? To clean first all files if there are any at all child nodes(sub directories if there are any) then to delete the child nodes(directories).

This is the DeleteFile method:

```
private void DeleteFile(string remoteFile, bool fileordir)
        {
            remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace('\\', '/');
            if (remoteFile.StartsWith("root"))
            {
                remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace("root", string.Empty);
            }
            string deleteRequest = txtHost.Text + remoteFile;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + deleteRequest);
            if (fileordir == false)
            {
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
            }
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.UseBinary = false;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            sr.ReadToEnd();
            string StatusCode = response.StatusDescription;
            sr.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
```

And this is the RemoveDirectory method that also inside i'm calling to the method RemoveDirectoriesRecursive:

```
private void RemoveDirectory(string remoteFile, bool fileordir)
        {
            RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(treeView1.SelectedNode);
            remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace('\\', '/');
            if (remoteFile.StartsWith("root"))
            {
                remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace("root", string.Empty);
            }
            string deleteRequest = txtHost.Text + remoteFile;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + deleteRequest);
            if (fileordir == true)
            {
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;
            }
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.UseBinary = false;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            sr.ReadToEnd();
            string StatusCode = response.StatusDescription;
            sr.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
```

The method DeleteFile is working if for example the selected node in the treeView1 is /test.jpg or /b/test.jpg

Also the method RemoveDirectory is working if the selectednode from the treeView1 is for exampe /b or /tempdir and the directory is empty.

The problem is when the the selected node have inside child nodes and more files in the child nodes.

EDIT

This is what i tried now.
I'm calling the RemoveDirectoriesRecursive from inside the RemoveDirectory.

```
private void RemoveDirectory(string remoteFile, bool fileordir)
        {
            remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace('\\', '/');
            if (remoteFile.StartsWith("root"))
            {
                remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace("root", string.Empty);
            }
            string deleteRequest = txtHost.Text + remoteFile;
            RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(treeView1.SelectedNode,deleteRequest);
```

Then in the RemoveDirectoriesRecursive:

```
public void RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(TreeNode ParentNode, string path)
{
    if (ParentNode.GetNodeCount(true) >= 0)
    {
        // go over all the nodes
        foreach (TreeNode subnode in ParentNode.Nodes)
        {
            string ss = (string)subnode.Tag;

            // if the node is a file then delete it
            if (subnode.Tag != null)
            {
                if (ss.Equals("file"))
                {
                    DeleteFile(path + "\\" + subnode.Text, false);
                }
            }

            // otherwise, if the node is a directory call the recursion
            else
            {
                RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(subnode, path + "\\" + subnode.Text);
            }

        }
    }
```

In this case i'm trying to delete empty directories. The ParentNode is directory name A and inside there are two child nodes(sub directories) name 1 and 2

So the variable path contain: ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/A
Abd ParentNode contain A

The problem is the place i'm calling RemoveDirectoriesRecursive method inside the RemoveDirectory is not good since it will be called each time it's a directory over and over again.

I messed it up.

Where should i call the method RemoveDirectoriesRecursive ? And what should be in path ?

Comment: your new `RemoveDirectory` does not execute a delete command. The path you should pass to the `RemoveDirectoriesRecursive` is the path of the `TreeNode`. i am assuming the inner nodes only contain the name and not the full path. Moreover you should add a Delete command at the end of the recursive function `RemoveDirectoriesRecursive` so that the directory will be deleted (note: this happens after the directory is empty from files and sub directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure how the name of the nodes are represented but i made some changes to your function to make it recursive.
it might need some minor changes in order to fit the way the paths are represented in your code.

```
public void RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(TreeNode ParentNode, string path)
{
    if (ParentNode.GetNodeCount(true) > 0)
    {
        // go over all the nodes
        foreach (TreeNode subnode in ParentNode.Nodes)
        {
            string ss = (string) subnode.Tag;

            // if the node is a file then delete it
            if (ss.Equals("file"))
            {
                DeleteFile(path + "\\" + subnode.Text, false);
            } 

            // otherwise, if the node is a directory call the recursion
            else if (ss.Equals("directory"))
            {
                RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(subnode, path + "\\" + subnode.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    // finally after we deleted inner files and directories
    // delete this directory as well
    RemoveDirectory(path, true);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: cOdeMonk3y can you look at my question at the bottom i did EDIT with what i tried maybe you can show me how to fix it ? How to use it the RemoveDirectoriesRecursive method ? Where to call it and what should be in path ? I gave an example for trying to delete a directory with sub directories inside.

Comment: your new `RemoveDirectory` does not execute a delete command. The path you should pass to the `RemoveDirectoriesRecursive` is the path of the `TreeNode`. i am assuming the inner nodes only contain the name and not the full path. Moreover you should add a Delete command at the end of the recursive function `RemoveDirectoriesRecursive` so that the directory will be deleted (note: this happens after the directory is empty from files and sub directories)

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it, it sounds like you need to have two completely separate recursive calls. You could supply a boolean parameter to the function `DeleteFolders`. If it is true, the function will delete folders, otherwise it will only delete files. Then you just all the function twice, once with `DeleteFolders`=true and once with `DeleteFolders`=false. All the recursive calls will just pass the value of `DeleteFolders` to the next level. Only the root level will supply a `true` or `false` value to the parameter.